# Select value smaller than Last one

Tags: mysql

TableA

```
    | Col1 | Col2 | NumCol |
    |    1 | a    |   1000 |
    |    2 | b    |   1001 |
    |    3 | c    |    900 |
    |    4 | d    |   1005 |
    |    5 | e    |   1004 |
```

I want to select rows where NumCol (e.g 3rd row NumCol is 900) is smaller than earlier Col1's NumCol (e.g 2nd row NumCol is 1001)

My results should be 3rd and 5th rows

Im sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

Use lag function If your version permit

```
Select *
From(
Select *,
Lag(value) over (order by id) previous_value
From foo
) V
Where value < previous_value
```

A tutorial for lag function

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/